# How to compile a Maya Plug-in on OS X?

Tags: xcode, macos, plugins, maya

I'm trying to write a simple tool that let me export something from Maya into my own file format. I'm new to Maya and I don't have a clue about how to write a plug-in for it. Searching the internet I found a promising site and I tried to compile an example. The author provides a Visual-C++ project and a Linux Makefile, but nothing for OS X of course.Does someone know how to setup a project for Maya in Xcode?  I just can't get it working, and I don't know where the libs and headers for the maya stuff are located.

Comment: Linux makefile can be run in Mac OS X terminal. Visual C++ can't.

Comment: thx. It seems that no document about setting up in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need specific versions of gcc and many standard libraries, which will vary depending on the version of Maya that you have.  Check the Maya docs and it should list what you need.

I'm not overly familiar with Xcode, but there should be a way to get it to invoke a makefile as your build operation.